# How to get the service locator that Jersey is currently using

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0

I have a scenario that Jersey 2.13 (with HK2 as DI) is loaded up in Tomcat and on the same JVM (I start it up from a startup servlet) a [netty-socket-io server](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) is running. I want this second server's methods to have access to the injected classes that the rest of my web app is using and I wouldn't like to introduce another dependency injection framework just for that.

I read that you can get a ServiceLocatorProvider in Jersey for doing this [here](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.6/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/ServiceLocatorProvider.html) but you need to have a context provided while my methods are completely separated.

Comment: Can't you just @Inject ServiceLocator locator; into some Jersey service and use that?

Comment: How do I find it from a class that is not running under the same container(tomcat) but on the same JVM?

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31943129/2587435)