# jersey + grizzly + hk2: Dependency injection, but not into resource

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, grizzly, hk2

Following up on [Jersey + HK2 + Grizzly: Proper way to inject EntityManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081840/jersey-hk2-grizzly-proper-way-to-inject-entitymanager), I would like to understand how it is possible use dependency injection in classes which are *not jersey resources*.

As an example, I might have background tasks running in an ExecutorService, and they might need an EntityManager. If I attempt to `@Inject` the EntityManager into the class, nothing happens. Injecting it into a `@Path`-annotated jersey resource class, injecting works fine.

The application is running as a standalone JVM, not on a Java EE application server.

**Update:** I have created a [test scenario](https://github.com/hankipanky/GrizzlyHk2Test) to demonstrate what I mean. The code is running a standalone Grizzly server with a Jersey resource, as well as an ExecutorService. A `Callable` is submitted to the ExecutorService.

Injection of the EntityManager into the resource works, but not into the Callable. There the EntityManager remains `null`.

Please advise if the code is better kept here than on github.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So to really understand how HK2 works, you should become familiar with its [`ServiceLocator`](https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html). It is analogous to Spring `ApplicationContext`, which is the main container for the DI framework.

In a standalone app, you could bootstrap the DI container simply by doing

```
ServiceLocatorFactory locatorFactory = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance();
ServiceLocator serviceLocator = locatorFactory.create("TestLocator");
ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new EntityManagerProvider());
```

Now your `EntityManagerProvider` is registered into the container. You can lookup the `EntityManager` simply by doing

```
EntityManager em = serviceLocator.getService(EntityManager.class);
```

Now in order to be able to take advantage of injection by the container, the service needs to be managed by the container. For example say you have this

```
public class BackgroundTask implements Callable<String> {

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        ...
}
```

which you actually do. The problem is, the `BackgroundTask` is not managed by the container. So even in a standalone bootstrap (like the three lines of code above), instantiating the task

```
BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask();
```

does nothing, as far as injection, as the task class is not managed by the container, *and* you are creating it yourself. If you wanted it managed, there a few ways to register it to the container. You've discovered one already (use an `AbstractBinder`) and register the binder to the `ServiceLocator`. Then instead of instantiating the class yourself, you just request it, like the `EntityManager` example above.

Or you can simply explicitly inject the task, i.e

```
BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(); 
serviceLocator.inject(task);
```

What that did was cause the locator to lookup the `EntityManager` and inject it into your task.

So how does this all fit in with Jersey? Jersey (partly) handles lookup of services and injection into resources during it's runtime. That's why it work's in your Jersey application. When the `EntityManager` is needed, it looks up the service an injects it into the resource instance.

So the next question is, if the tasks are being run outside the scope the Jersey application, how can you inject the task? For the most part, all the above is pretty much the gist of it. Jersey has it's own `ServiceLocator`, and it's not easy to try a obtain a reference to it. We could give Jersey *our* `ServiceLocator`, but Jersey ultimately still creates it's *own* locator and will populate it with *our* locator. So ultimately there would still be two locators. You can see an example of what I mean in the refactored code below, where it check the references in the `ServiceLocatorFeature`.

But if you do want to provide the `ServiceLocator` to Jersey, you can pass it to the Grizzly server factory method

```
server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
        URI.create(BASE_URI),
        config, 
        serviceLocator
);
```

Now you can still use your locator outside of Jersey. Honestly though, in this case, you could *not* involve Jersey at all and just keep your own locator, and just register the `EntityManagerProvider` with both Jersey and your `ServiceLocator`. I don't see it really making much difference, except for the extra line of code. Functionally, I don't see any change.

To learn more about HK2, I highly recommend thoroughly going through the [user guide](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/index.html). You'll learn a lot about what goes on under the hood with Jersey, and also learn about features that you can incorporate into a Jersey application.

Below is the complete refactor of your test. I didn't really change much. Any changes I made are pretty much discussed above.

```
public class DependencyInjectionTest {

    private final ServiceLocatorFactory locatorFactory
            = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance();
    private ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    private final static String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8888/";
    private final static String OK = "OK";
    private HttpServer server;
    private ExecutorService backgroundService;

    public class EntityManagerProvider extends AbstractBinder
            implements Factory<EntityManager> {

        private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

        public EntityManagerProvider() {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("derbypu");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(this).to(EntityManager.class);
            System.out.println("EntityManager binding done");
        }

        @Override
        public EntityManager provide() {
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            System.out.println("New EntityManager created");
            return em;
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(EntityManager em) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public class BackgroundTask implements Callable<String> {

        @Inject
        EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Background task started");
            Assert.assertNotNull(em);   // will throw exception

            System.out.println("EntityManager is not null");
            return OK;
        }
    }

    public class ServiceLocatorFeature implements Feature {

        @Override
        public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
            ServiceLocator jerseyLocator
                    = org.glassfish.jersey.ServiceLocatorProvider
                            .getServiceLocator(context);

            System.out.println("ServiceLocators are the same: "
                    + (jerseyLocator == serviceLocator));

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Path("/test")
    public static class JerseyResource {

        @Inject
        EntityManager em;

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public Response doGet() {
            System.out.println("GET request received");
            Assert.assertNotNull(em);

            System.out.println("EntityManager is not null");
            return Response.ok()
                    .entity(OK)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        serviceLocator = locatorFactory.create("TestLocator");
        ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind(serviceLocator, new EntityManagerProvider());

        System.out.println("Setting up");
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(new ServiceLocatorFeature());
        //config.register(new EntityManagerProvider());
        config.register(JerseyResource.class);
        // can't find a better way to register the resource
        //config.registerInstances(JerseyResource.class);   

        server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create(BASE_URI),
                config, serviceLocator
        );

        backgroundService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
        server.shutdownNow();
        backgroundService.shutdownNow();
    }

    @Test
    public void testScheduledBackgroundTask() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertTrue(server.isStarted());

        BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask();
        serviceLocator.inject(task);
        Future<String> f = backgroundService.submit(task);
        System.out.println("Background task submitted");

        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(OK, f.get());   // forces Exception
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();

            Assert.fail();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testBackgroundTask() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertTrue(server.isStarted());

        BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask();
        serviceLocator.inject(task);
        System.out.println("Background task instantiated");

        Assert.assertEquals(OK, task.call());
    }

    @Test
    public void testResource() {
        Assert.assertTrue(server.isStarted());

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URI);

        Response r = target.path("test")
                .request()
                .get();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, r.getStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(OK, r.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Another thing I might mention is that you should need only one `EntityManagerFactory` for the application. It's expensive to create, and creating one every time the `EntityManager` is needed is not a good idea. See one solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28122910/2587435).

Comment: Your detailed response has inspired me. I've found another way to make hk2 aware of injectable classes: `@Service` and the [HK2 Inhabitant Generator](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b29/inhabitant-generator.html#HK2_Metadata_Generator).

Comment: Could you please explain how to get a reference of jersey's own locator from the outside? I cannot find an answer on this and its the only thread I found here.

Comment: @arisalexis You can with some hack like using a holder class, and setting the locator in that class through some static method. You can can do that anywhere the ServiceLocator is available, for instance in a Feature, as shown above, or almost anywhere else. The ServiceLocator can be injected into most places in a Jersey app. Like it said though, it's pretty much a hack. You have to think of cases also where you have services in a request scope. If you try to access those services outside of the Jersey application, you will get a not in request scope error. singletons a per request objects work

Comment: Once you set the locator, just access it through the holder. I've never used this for a real application, so I can provide any pros and cons, side from the request scope issue... (at the end of above comment, I meant "per lookup object" not "per request object")

Comment: I don't don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but it seems like maybe you need to look for some other type of integration strategy :-(

Comment: I like the stabdalone approach its jist that i need to access an injected service which has a lot of other injected dependencies already binded for jersey so i thought its much easier to get this reference but i think i will just inject in another service locator what i want and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Statement**: Implementation of Dependency Injection using Grizzly and Jersey

Please follow the below steps to do the same –

- List item Create a class called Hk2Feature which implements Feature -

  ```
  package com.sample.di;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
  import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
  @Provider
  public class Hk2Feature implements Feature {
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
      context.register(new MyAppBinder());
      return true;
    }
  }
  ```
- List item Create a class called MyAppBinder which extends AbstractBinder and you need to register all the services here like below –

  ```
  package com.sample.di;
  import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
  public class MyAppBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(MainService.class).to(MainService.class);
    }
  }
  ```
- List item Now, it’s time to write your own services and inject all the required services in your appropriate controllers like below code –
  package com.sample.di;

  ```
  public class MainService {
    public String testService(String name) {
      return “Hi” + name + “..Testing Dependency Injection using Grizlly Jersey “;
    }
  }
  package com.sample.di;
  import javax.inject.Inject;
  import javax.ws.rs.GET;
  import javax.ws.rs.Path;
  import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
  import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
  import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
  @Path(“/main”)
  public class MainController {
      @Inject
      public MainService mainService;
      @GET
      public String get(@QueryParam(“name”) String name) {
          return mainService.testService(name);
      }
      @GET
      @Path(“/test”)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public String ping() {
          return “OK”;
      }
  }
  ```

Now hit the url http://localhost:8080/main?name=Tanuj and you will get your result. This is how you can achieve dependency injection in Grizzly Jersey application. Find the detailed implementation of the above skeleton in my [repo](https://guptakumartanuj.wordpress.com/2017/08/01/dependecny-injection-using-grizzly-and-jersey/). Happy Coding

Comment: Your post is missing the question, which was about DI into non-jersey-managed classes. Your "MainController" is a Jersey Service.